# Accessing ConfigurationManager from Orchard view

Tags: c#, web-config, orchardcms

I'm trying to access an AppSettings key/value in my web.config from an Orchard theme view. Something like this:

```
@System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AccountID"]
```

I'm getting the following exception when I try to do so:

```
The type or namespace name 'ConfigurationManager' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Configuration' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
```

I checked and the System.Configuration assembly is referenced from both the Orchard.Web project and my custom theme's project.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: that is a bad idea. why don't you send it down with a model?

Comment: I'm trying to use it to grab our google analytics account ID to use in the layout view. Seems like overkill to create a module for that. Is there an easier way to get it into the model?

Comment: Use a module from the gallery to add your google analytics code?